# Set proxy for Hosted Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Im new to chef. I have set up a workstation and a hosted chef server(`https://api.opscode.com/organizations/org-name`). However when I use the `knife client-list` command it shows me an error that the connection could not be established. Im using my office network and to connect to the internet I use a proxy. 
How do I establish the connection to the chef server using this proxy?
I have the following details about the proxy :
IP address, port number,domain,username,password

I tried to add the proxy settings to `knife.rb` file as follows :

```
https_proxy "http://ipaddress:port"
https_proxy_user "domain\username"
https_proxy_pass "password"
```

But i get the following error - `Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.`

Please help!

Comment: Trying running knife with the "-c" to specify the knife configuration file (just in case knife was picking up an alternative file). You're using the documented mechanism (http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_knife.html) Are the credentials correct?

Comment: Yea, the proxy is connecting, but it looks like your authz is incorrect.

Comment: I found out the problem. the user needed an escape character as well
https_proxy_user "domain\\username"